# The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

Using .NET Core 6 I have the following code:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSitemap<T>(this IServiceCollection services) where T : ISitemapService 
{
    services.AddTransient<ISitemapService, T>(); 
    return services;
}
```

I get an error:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method
>
> The method `AddTransient` expects a class that implements `ISitemapService`.

What am I missing?

Comment: May be `where T : class, ISitemapService`

Comment: Of course ... I added ISitemapService, class but somehow I was getting an error to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that any parameter is of type class, as mentioned in the comments by Eldar, like so:

```
where T : class, ISitemapService
```

This is so the generic parameter is constrained only to complex types, and not lets say structs or premitives, so that you can instantiate a new T